# How to resolve JLS3 cannot be resolved or is not a field error in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.*;

public class AST {
    public static void maain(String arge[]) {
        String str = "someString"; 
        char[] source = str.toCharArray();
     ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);  // handles JDK 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6
     parser.setSource(source);
     // In order to parse 1.5 code, some compiler options need to be set to 1.5
     Map options = JavaCore.getOptions();
     JavaCore.setComplianceOptions(JavaCore.VERSION_1_5, options);
     parser.setCompilerOptions(options);
     CompilationUnit result = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
}
}
```

I am trying to parse java code using AST PARSER in eclipse.
How to resolve "JLS3 cannot be resolved or is not a field" error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have called your class `AST` so the compiler is looking for `JLS3` in your `AST` class, not the JDT `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST` class.

You can either rename your `AST` class to something that does not clash or you can use the full name of the JDT class:

```
ASTParser.newParser(org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST.JLS3);
```